# Alternating output in bash for loop from two grep

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to search through files and extract two pieces of relevant information every time they appear in the file. The code I currently have:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Utilized reads from ustacks output" > reads.txt
str1="utilized reads:"
str2="Parsing"
for file in /home/desaixmg/novogene/stacks/sample01/conda_ustacks.o*; do
    reads=$(grep $str1 $file | cut -d ':' -f 3
    samples=$(grep $str2 $file | cut -d '/' -f 8
    echo $samples $reads >> reads.txt
done
```

It is doing each line for the file (the files have varying numbers of instances of these phrases) and gives me the output per row for each file:

```
PopA_15.fq 1081264
PopA_16.fq PopA_17.fq 1008416 554791
PopA_18.fq PopA_20.fq PopA_21.fq 604610 531227 595129
...
```

I want it to match each instance (i.e. 1st instance of both greps next two each other):

```
PopA_15.fq 1081264
PopA_16.fq 1008416
PopA_17.fq 554791
PopA_18.fq 604610
PopA_20.fq 531227
PopA_21.fq 595129
...
```

How do I do this? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow, so it means `PopA_18.fq PopA_20.fq PopA_21.fq 604610 531227 595129` you need first `Pop` value and `st digit value in each line, please confirm once?

Comment: Thanks! I want each population read value to line up with the appropriate pop.  I revised the sample output above to better show this hopefully...

Comment: Please check my answer now and let me know if that helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that your Input_file is same as sample shown and number of columns are even on each line with 1 `PopA` value and other will be with digit values. Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=(NF/2);i++){print $i,$((NF/2)+i)}}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
PopA_15.fq 1081264
PopA_16.fq 1008416
PopA_17.fq 554791
PopA_18.fq 604610
PopA_20.fq 531227
PopA_21.fq 595129
```

In case you want to pass output of a command to `awk` command then you could do like `your command | awk command...` no need to add Input_file to above `awk` command.

Comment: Thank you! I think I had poorly explained the problem, but I found another solution.  I do need to start learning awk though...

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working for me...any tips for more efficient code are definitely welcome

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Utilized reads from ustacks output" > reads.txt
str1="utilized reads:"
str2="Parsing"
for file in /home/desaixmg/novogene/stacks/sample01/conda_ustacks.o*; do
    reads=$(grep $str1 $file | cut -d ':' -f 3)
    samples=$(grep $str2 $file | cut -d '/' -f 8)
    paste <(echo "$samples" | column -t) <(echo "$reads" | column -t) >> reads.txt
done
```

This provides the desired output described above.

Comment: Why the `echo`s? Why the command substitutions? `paste <(grep "$str1" "$file" | cut -d: -f 3 | column -t) <(grep "$str2" "$file" | cut -d/ -f8 | column -t)` -- that's actually more efficient by far, since it doesn't require the output from `grep` to be stored in memory; the writes block until `paste` is ready to read them.